# Aliasing "direction" in python. Modifying the row of a numpy array through aliasing

Tags: alias, numpy-ndarray

So, I'm working on a simulation project. I have a dictionary where I stored a series of 1D numpy arrays (vectors basically) with same length. This due to convience. Because, for reasons related to the simulation itself, it easier for me, sometimes, to work on this vectors through the dictionary keys. At the same time, I also need performance in certain computations. In these cases, it is much more convient to work on the matrix that has those vectors as rows. I need to do some tensor computation.

I thought I could solve the problem through proper aliasing. But there's a catch! It works only in one "direction". It seems like I can create aliases for each matrix's rows and use those aliases as values in the dictionary but not vice versa. I cannot create the dictionary first with values and then build a matrix where each row is in fact an alias for the dictionary's values.

So, basically, this works:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1,2],[-1,-2]])
>>> dict = {1:A[0], 2:A[1]}
```

In fact, if I change some dictionary values (being careful not to override the alias)

```
dict[1][:] = np.array([100,200])
```

This is what I get:

```
>>> print(A)

[[100 200]
 [ -1  -2]]
```

On the contrary if I reverse the process:

```
dict = {1: np.array([1,2]), 2: np.array([-1,-2])}
A = np.array([dict[1],dict[2]])

dict[1][:] = np.array([100,200])


>>> print(A)
[[ 1  2]
 [-1 -2]]
```

seems like a copy of the two vectors is created instead. Even using np.vstack() (instead of np.array()) doesn't change the result.